# ReferenceError: expect is not defined

Tags: google-chrome, jasmine, karma-runner, google-chrome-headless, chrome76

When running latest chrome Version 76.0.3809.100 karma unit test in jasmine are failing with error message **ReferenceError: expect is not defined**
Those unit tests worked just fine in previous version of chrome.
Those unit test passes on Safari and Firefox.
It look like there is a breaking changes / new bug introduces in the latest version of chrome.
Did any one encountered this issue too?

Comment: Same here. All our unit tests fail on every dev machine that has chrome 76. Our unit test stack is Karma, angular JS and chrome

Answer (score 0):

Although the error seems different, one of the reason can be incompatible chrome driver. Please try upgrading your `chromedriver` to 76.0.0.